# How to load variables from a parent code?

Tags: matlab, function, variables

I have the following "parent" code, call it `solve.m`:

```
s1 = .01;
v = 1;
fun1 = @rootd;
x0 =  [.2, .3, .4]
options = optimset('MaxFunEvals',100000,'MaxIter', 10000 );
x1 = fsolve(fun1,x0, options)
```

I also have the following code for function `rootd.m`

```
function D = rootd(x1)
F = @(p) 1 - ((3.*x1(3).^2 - 7.*x1(3) + 6).*(x1(2)./p -1))./(2.*x1(3).*(1-x1(3)));
H = @(p) (1 - ((3.*x1(3).^2 - 7.*x1(3) + 6).*(x1(2)./p -1))./(2.*x1(3).*(1-x1(3)))).^2; 
F1 = @(p) 1 - ((6 - 7.*x1(3) + 3.*x1(3)^2).*(min(v,x1(2))./p - 1 ))./(2.*x1(3).*(1-x1(3))); 
H1 = @(p) (1 - ((6 - 7.*x1(3) + 3.*x1(3)^2).*(min(v,x1(2))./p - 1))./(2.*x1(3).*(1-x1(3)))).^2; 

g = @(p) integral(@(p) F(p), x1(1), x1(2)); 
f = @(p) integral(@(p) F1(p), x1(1), (min(v,x1(2))));  
h = @(p) integral(@(p) H1(p), x1(1),(min(v,x1(2))));

D(1) = g(x1) - s1; 
D(2) = x1(3).*(2-x1(3)).*(v - min(v, x1(2))) - (((x1(3)^2)/2).*h(x1)) + (2.*x1(3)...
 - (1/2).*x1(3).^2).*f(x1) - ((v-min(v, x1(2))) + f(x1) -s1); 
D(3) = (6 - 7.*x1(3) + 3.*x1(3)^2).*min(v, x1(2))./((2-x1(3)).*(3-x1(3))) - x1(1);
end
```

When I run the parent code, I obtain:

> Undefined function or variable 's1'.

I understand that I need to define variable `s1` in `rootd.m` function.  But I would like that the function automatically loads `s1` from `solve.m`.

Comment: What lang? Put it in the tags

Comment: You must `import` the symbols in the referenced notebook.   (How can the system "automatically" know which you mean if different *.m contain the same symbol?!)

Answer (score 0):

Unless you make the variable global you can not access it. But that might not be the best idea in matlab.

You can just pass the variable in as a parameter to the function.

```
s1 = .01;
fun1 = @(pars)rootd(s1,pars);
```

This just defines `rootd` to be a single parameter function (something that several of the optimization function require), although you can pass multiple one. You `rootd` function can then look like this:

```
function D = rootd(s1,x1)
    ...
end
```